# Chart bar alignment

Tags: c#, user-interface, charts

I'm trying to create a bar chart. the problem is I can't align the x-axis values to the left of each bar. I don't want the x-axis values to be centered at each bar. I looked for through many properties of the chart but I wasn't lucky enough to find that kind of property.

This is what i currently have

[image: x-axis values centered at each bar]

This is what I'm trying to acheive:
[image: x-axis values aligned to the left of each bar]

Comment: Please post what code you have tried so far.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet. I just added some points to the series of the chart. 
I'm just creating the specific layout.

Comment: This is simply not how it __should__ be. The Columns (and for that matter also Bars) are __centered__ over the x-values (resp. Y-Values). Their width is in no way related to the x-values.